# Regex not matching correctly?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I am trying to search for a subject for a match to the regular expression given in the pattern but it is not working correctly.
I want to match a number/10 then a postcode

for example if the string is "hello 3/10 HU2" i want the preg_match function to match the 3 and the postcode and it needs to be in that order

the strange thing is when i try the preg_match in the opposite order so HU2 3/10 it works but when i change the code around it does not recognize the value 3.

Any help would be appreciated

the code below works for the order HU2 3/10 but i need it in the opposite order

```
<?php

    preg_match('/([A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]?) ([0-9]{1,2})/', "HU2 3/10", $matches);    

    echo $matches[1];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $matches[2];


?>
```

Comment: What prevents you from flipping the pattern? I mean if you need the opposite order, order it in the opposite way. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @hakre I think the problem is that if you just flip it, it returns `10` and not `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change it around, you have to include the `/10` in the pattern. Note that you can change the delimiters so that you don't have to escape the forward slash:

```
preg_match('~([0-9]{1,2})/10 ([A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]?)~', "3/10 HU2", $matches);
```

The `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`. Also, if `10` is a variable number, that's easy to take into account, too:

```
preg_match('~(\d{1,2})/\d+ ([A-Za-z]{1,2}\d[A-Za-z0-9]?)~', "3/10 HU2", $matches);
```

As a final optimisation, the use of the `i` modifiers, let's you leave out half of the letters (it makes the pattern case-insensitive):

```
preg_match('~(\d{1,2})/\d+ ([A-Z]{1,2}\d[A-Z0-9]?)~i', "3/10 HU2", $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not matching the /10, are you?

```
(\d{1,2})/10 ([A-Za-z]{1,2}\d\w?)
```

matches

hello 3/10 HU2

group 1: 3
group 2: HU2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that I've tried with various strings and seems to work:

```
Regex: ([^ ]+) *(\d*\/10) *([A-Za-z0-9]+) *(.*)

Test strings:
1) hello 3/10 HU2
2) test this regex 3/10 HU2 param1 param2
3) testid 33323/10 HU2332GG param1 param2
```

I'm not quite sure on all the requirements but this can be the basis for your regex. You can also use the online regex tool to quickly verify your regex here: 
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html